# Show JQuery image slider over flash website

Tags: jquery, flash, image, slider, slideshow

Currently I am building flash website.
But I would like to have images presented using JQuery slider Galleria http://galleria.aino.se/
Basically, the web is built of the menu on the left. when clicking one of the items from the menu i would like the Jquery Slider show in the middle (over the flash, may be box 700x500).

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<object ...>
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <embed ... wmode="transparent">
</embed>
</object>
```

Is suppose to do the trick.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html has documentation on wmode values and what they are suppose to do. It is not complete I don't see value="gpu" ... http://niquimerret.com/?p=159 ... wmode=opaque may also do the trick because it turns off GPU rendering which may be the cause of the flash appearing over other content.